# pm ERR! Unexpected end of input

Tags: npm

when I type `NPM INIT` I get this error:

```
ERROR :pm ERR! Unexpected end of input
```

I have installed node JS and check the version
and I get this error when I try to initialize the project

Comment: npm cache clean --force

Comment: in the project dir ?

Comment: Yeah, you can do in project directory.

Comment: i get the same error

Comment: which type of project you are running ?

Comment: node js project

Comment: Can you paste your path like where you are creating the project, this can happen if you are trying to create in root like in c drive if you are using windows

Comment: C:\Users\Lenovo\Desktop\mainFiles\mainfolders\app>

Comment: can you please try using the administrator cmd ?

Comment: i did and i get the same error

Comment: what is node version ?

Comment: the last long term support v14.17.0

Comment: can you try installing the node 12 version and then create the project ?

Comment: i did and the same problem still exists